# Docker: How to find the network mode from inside a container?

Tags: docker, networking, containers, system

Docker network mode includes *host*, *bridge* and others. Getting the network mode outside the container is easy. But how to get what network mode this container is using inside this very container?

Comment: Why do you need to know it?  Can you include some relevant application code that's having problems?

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to know how much uploading bandwidth the container is using from inside the container. After some research, I find that it can be done by reading this file: `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes`. But only when the container's network mode is `host` will that work. Thus, I want to find a way to get the network mode inside the container.(I do not have the authority to opreate outside the container)